# "QueryFailedError{Message: workflow must handle at least one decision task before it can be queried}" when trying to run a workflow

Tags: cadence-workflow

I get the aforementioned error when trying to start a workflow (and query it for init). It took me a while to get into names of things - after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904129/what-exactly-is-a-cadence-decision-task) it is more clear what decision task really is, however I think I am still a bit lost in terminology. So I believe in my case decision task takes longer than 1 sec (queryFirstDecisionTaskWaitTime). Is this wait time in any way configurable? Has anyone experienced similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to "configure" the `queryFirstDecisionTaskWaitTime` by setting request timeout.

For example, in golang that's just the context timeout when sending the query requests to Cadence server.

Tested in CLI:

```
% date ; ~/cadence/cadence --ct 10 --do qlong wf query -w helloworld_b721724d-11f9-4b5b-a158-2bda4a230297 --query_type "__stack_trace" ; date
Thu Oct  8 14:46:47 PDT 2020
Error: Query workflow failed.
Error Details: QueryFailedError{Message: workflow must handle at least one decision task before it can be queried}
('export CADENCE_CLI_SHOW_STACKS=1' to see stack traces)
Thu Oct  8 14:46:56 PDT 2020
```

Note: --ct 10 means we uses 10 seconds as context timeout for this command.

As a minimum, defaultQueryFirstDecisionTaskWaitTime is one second. Currently there is no way to change this minimum boundary. And I don't think we need that as you can configure per each request :D

BTW, thank you for asking questions in StackOverfolw, that helps us to preserve knowledge for the community better.

Comment: Ok, I am using a context with a timeout of 60 seconds so I believe timeout is not an issue in this case

Comment: It's working for me. I just updated my answer with an example to try it in CLI. Can you also try that? I guess somewhere wrong in your code about timeout.

Comment: I will double check and get back to you

Comment: It seems like a workflow get stucked in `DecisionTaskScheduled` state. Could it be due to communication problem with Cadence server?

Comment: Answered it. Thank you for your help anyway! One mystery less in this Cadence Leviathan :D

Comment: Yeah, congrat! That’s a common mistake using Cadence. BTW I think my answer is still most relevant to your question:D if you think so please accept it .

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured out what it was - my `tasklist` was not configured properly. So it was the reason workflow is stuck in `DecisionTaskScheduled` state