# How to return the processing result of a signal?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Especially if the signal processing needs to invoke an/some activities, how can I achieve that?

I tried to return data or exception but it doesn't work.

Data cannot be returned from signal method. Throwing exception will block workflow execution.

Answer (score 2):

### Common mistakes

It's wrong to return data in a signal method, or throw an exception -- because signal method is meant to be Asynchronous. The processing must be like Kafka processing messages and you can't return the result via the method returning.

So below code will **NOT** work:

```java
public class SampleWorkflow{
   public Result mySignalMethod(SignalRequest req){
      Result result = activityStub.execute(req)
      if(...){
          throw new RuntimeException(...)
      }
   return result
   }

}
```

### What should you do

What you must do:

- Make sure signal don't return anything
- Use a query method to return the results
- In signal method processing, store the results into workflow state so that query can return the states

A bonus if you also use [the design pattern to store signal request into a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654251/what-is-the-best-way-pattern-to-process-a-signal-in-cadence-temporal-workflow), and let workflow method to process the signal. This will give you some benefits

- Guarantee FIFO ordering of signal processing
- Make sure reset workflow won't run into issues -- after reset, signals  will be preserved and moved to earlier position of the workflow history. Sometimes workflow are not initialized to replay the signals.
- Also make exception handling easier

See this design pattern in sample code: [Cadence Java sample](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/hello/HelloSignal.java#L67)/[Temporal java sample](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/main/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/hello/HelloSignal.java#L85)

If we applied all above, the sample code should be like below :

```java
public class SampleWorkflow{

   private Queue<SignalRequest> queue = new Queue<>();
   private Response<Result> lastSignalResponse;

   public void myWorkflowMethod(){
        Async.procedure(
                () -> {
                    while (true) {
                        Workflow.await(() -> !queue.isEmpty());
                        final SignalRequest req =
                                queue.poll();
                        // alternatively, you can use async to start an activity:  
                        try{
                             Result result = activityStub.execute(req); 
                        }catch (ActivityException e){
                             lastSignalResponse = new Response( e );
                        }

                        if(...){
                            lastSignalResponse = new Response( new RuntimeException(...) );
                        }else{
                             lastSignalResponse = new Response( result);  
                        }
                    }
                });

      ...
   }

   public Response myQueryMethod(){
       return lastSignalResponse;
   }

   public Result mySignalMethod(SignalRequest req){
      queue.add(req)
   }

}
```

And in the application code, you should signal and then query the workflow to get the result:

```java
  workflowStub.mySignalMethod(req)
  Response response = workflowStub.myQueryMethod()
```

Follow this [sample-Cadence](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/hello/HelloAsync.java) / [sample-Temporal](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/main/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/hello/HelloAsync.java) if you want to use aysnc activity

### Why

- Signal is executed via [Workflow decision task(Workflow task in Temporal). A decision task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904129/what-exactly-is-a-cadence-decision-task/63964726#63964726) cannot return result. In current design, there is no mechanism to let a decision task return result to application code.
- [Throw exception in workflow code will either block the decision task or fail the workflow](https://community.temporal.io/t/throwing-exception-vs-failure-in-workflow/1059)).
- Query method is designed to return result. -- However, query cannot schedule activity or modify workflow states.
- It's a missing part to let app code to make a synchronous API call to update and return data. It needs a complicated design:  https://github.com/temporalio/proposals/pull/53