# What is Replay in Cadence/Temporal workflow?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

What is Replay in Cadence/Temporal workflow? Is it the same as "retry"?

Why can't I simply use my own logger in workflow code due to replay?

Answer (score 1):

“Retry” and "replay" are completely different.

**Replay is for rebuilding the workflow thread states(process/thread stack).**

Imagine this workflow code(in Java):

```java
 activityStub.doA()
 LOG.info("first log")
 activityStub.doB()
 LOG.info("second log")
```

If LOG is not from Workflow.getLogger or not wrapped by Workflow.isReplay, the first log will be printed more than one times — just depend on how many times the code got replayed.

The timeline of causing duplicated logs:

- After doA is completed, first log is printed.
- And then doB is executed, let say doB will take 1 minute.
- During the 1 minute, the worker crashes or got restarted.
- And then the doB completed.
- Then there will be a new [workflow task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904129/what-exactly-is-a-cadence-decision-task/63964726#63964726) to process the completion of doB.
- The workflow task will then executed in a new worker host, which requires a replay to rebuild the Stack until the code of doB. During the replay, assuming LOG is your own logger without wrapping by workflow.isReplay(), the first log will be printed again.
- And then doB will get completed and then the second log will be printed.

So at the end, you will see the logs:

```
first log
first log
second log
```